# Generate storyboard ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, storyboard

I want to do a slid-out menu in my app, but the problem is I dont find my storyboard in the project, there is a way to generated from the xib file ? or a new empty storyboard can do the job ?

Comment: Does a main.storyboard file exist in your project folder?

Comment: You can right click the project file, choose 'New File', 'User Interface', and 'Storyboard'.

Comment: @arcofclark and then how to do to get my viewController on it ? or i dont need to ?

Comment: i mean if i create a new storyboard, what to do after to linked with my viewController .... 

Or i dont need too ?

Comment: Create a new viewController in the new storyboard and copy the attributes and code from the old one.

Answer (score 1):

You better use a `.xib` instead of a `storyboard` for side menu.

See this GIT repo for side menu - recomend

https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu